# Absence of normality of residuals (lmer)

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, residuals

I’m running an analysis on Y coordinates of mouse clicks on a scale. These Y coordinates range from -200 to +200. I have created a new data frame on R and I have deleted data points that exceed these limits as they mean that participants didn’t click on the scale.

The scale was either presented upright or upside down (Scale 1 and Scale 2 respectively). I thus transformed all Scale 2 scores so that they are comparable to Scale 1 results.

I have since computed a generalised linear model on my Y variable with lmer and set various fixed and random effects. The R squared values show the model has substantial explanatory power and my variables of interest are significant although the part related to the fixed effects isn’t that great.

However, the problem I encounter is that when running my normality checks on my residuals these are not normal.

I have read that this is not really a problem in large samples and I do have data from 115 participants. Would it be ok to use this model and justify it by saying that my sample is large enough?

Are there any alternatives?

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: What family of response distributions did you select?  With such a large dataset it might not matter much, but generally you would want a distribution that is appropriate for your data with known limits.  Some people recommend a beta response family in such circumstances.  In practice, logistic regression has been known to work well even though the responses (suitably scaled to a $[0,1]$ range) are not binary.

Comment: Welcome to CV! It is generally helpful to include code chunks instead of screen shots of code so people can readily copy and paste your code into R. Can also screenshot the plots directly instead of taking pictures of it so they are easier to view.

Comment: @whuber Thank you so much for taking the time to respond. I didn't specify a response family so I assume it just used the default Gaussian distribution. In this case, do you recommend I keep my regression output or do I try to run a less sophisticated and non-parametric alternative such as a Friedman test? Thanks again!

Comment: Your residuals aren't remotely Gaussian.  That doesn't necessarily mean your model is useless, because it still likely is effective for estimating parameters.  But don't use it for prediction limits or other procedures that require a good estimate of the conditional distributions.  Formal normality testing is usually pointless : please [search our site about that](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+normality+test+score%3A5)